# Simulating mouse click event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm looking to extract data about Red Cards and Yellow Cards from a soccer match page.  One example of a match page is: http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/667743/MatchReport

As you can see on the website, the card data can only be accessed after clicking the "Card Situation" tab.  Therefore, when I use phantomjs to save the page content, it doesn't capture the Card Situation tab.  I know one solution would be to simulate a mouse click so that the HTML can be generated and then saved, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead try to fetch the AJAX requests it does when you click on the tab. For example, when I clicked on the tab you've mentioned, it made two AJAX requests:

1) http://www.whoscored.com/optamatchstatfeed/?matchId=667743&stageId=6849&teamId=684&type=14

2) http://www.whoscored.com/optamatchstatfeed/?matchId=667743&stageId=6849&teamId=297&type=14

And it's apparently one for each team. If you open any of the links above in the browser you'll notice a JSON response format. Like this one:

```
[[[],[[[3,3,'fk_foul_lost',[6]]]]]]
```

Now the rest is up to you. Enjoy. ;)